# Networking differences in Java

Tags: java, networking

//Java Socket Programming

In Java a client knows IP address and Port Number of the server, but how is the
server able to make a Socket Connection with the client(and make input and output
streams)? i.e how/when/where the server gets knowledge about the client.

Comment: The server doesn't make a socket connection with the client. The cleat makes a socket connection with the server.

Comment: @EJP, what is a cleat?

Comment: Oops iPad typo, I meant 'client'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client connects to the server using TCP/IP, and when the server receives the packets, the client's IP and other details are included.

Just like when someone calls you, you see what number is calling, or better yet their name (this would be similar to the DNS server knowing that the IP 192.0.0.1 is actually somedomain.com).